# Finding the max in a complex list - Python

Tags: python, list, mapping

I have a list a = [('b', 1), ('k',3), ('g',2), ('p',3)...]
The first tuple is a letter, and the 2nd is a count of how often the letter has occurred. I am trying to find the max occurrences of a letter (there can be more than one i.e. k=3 and p =3) and return the letter closest to 'a'.

My current logic is: find the highest count -> make another list and only append elements which have their 2nd tuple = highest count -> sort the list -> return the first tuple of the first element.

If there is a better method to do this in Python (and I am sure there is) I am all ears!

But either way, in Python what is the most efficient way to find the highest count?

Currently I am using the below method but it returns a list element not a number.

`max(a, key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

Comment: Oh also if you are going to answer this using a different method you can assume 'a' is just a string. i.e. a='kasdf asdlkj asdlkj fsdd'

Comment: `max(a, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]` will return the number...

Comment: why don't you use a Counter for that ?

Comment: Though it's probably not as efficient as max, you can use list.sort() or sorted() with a lambda function as the key...

Comment: The issue with Counter, though, is I don't find a way to sort the equally common items

Comment: At first you say, with things with the same count, you want "the letter closest to 'a'", but then you say, you only want the count, not the tuple.  If you don't want the letter when you're done, why sort by the letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort your list with key as 2-tuple with reversed count and char:

```
>>> a = [('b', 1), ('k',3), ('g',2), ('p',3)] 
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda t:(-t[1], t[0]))
[('k', 3), ('p', 3), ('g', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

or use `min` with same key:

```
>>> min(a, key=lambda t:(-t[1],t[0]))
('k', 3)
```

Comment: I really dislike code only answers with no explanation what so ever.

Comment: It also seems like an overkill to sort when looking for maximum.

Comment: Hi ndpu, I am new to lambda functions could you explain what that is doing?

Comment: @Mazzone lambda is inplace function definition. You can define some function `def fun(t): return (-t[1],t[0])` and use it as key: `key=fun` or use lambda function...

Answer (score 0):

Since you sometimes say you only want the count, let's do that first because it's the simplest and fastest, using a generator expression:

```
a = [('b', 1), ('k',3), ('g',2), ('p',3)]
max_count = max(count for (letter, count) in a)
print max_count
```

==> `3`

What if you really did care about the letters, or in general, cared about more than one of the elements in the tuples?

Python sorts (or compares) tuples by the first element, then if the first element is equal, by the second element, and so forth.  You want the tuple with the highest count and the earliest (lowest) string.  You can use key=function in a max(), min() or sorted() to give the thing you would like to sort by or compare by, which you might think was the max of

```
(count, backwards-sorting-letter??)
```

Except there is no simple way to make a string that sorts the opposite way from a given string.  But, instead of the max of that you look for the min of this:

```
(-count, letter)
```

Which is what ndpu did.  You need a function to turn `(letter, count)` into `(-count, letter)`.  Or in other words turn `a_tuple` into `(-a_tuple[1], a_tuple[0])`.

You could do that like

```
def the_order_I_want(a_tuple):
    return (-a_tuple[1], a_tuple[0])

print min(a, key=the_order_I_want)
```

=> `('k', 3)`

Or you could use a lambda expression, which is just a shortened way to write a function that returns something right away:

```
print min(a, key=lambda a_tuple: (-a_tuple[1], a_tuple[0]) )
```

=> `('k', 3)`

So now you have the winning tuple, but if you want the count by itself...

```
result_tuple = min(a, key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]) )
count = result_tuple[1]
```

or

```
letter, count = min(a, key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]) )
```